# Looking for distance history using google API (or other)

Tags: android, google-maps, gis, google-fit

I've been searching and i thought i could ask you directly in here.

I'm looking for an API (maybe Google) that does the same work as Google fit history API as of recording every distance you made and the transportation mode. It is not necessary for me to get the exact latitude or longitude by at least the number of kilometer/meter(or miles) made by day in cars/foot/run/bike by a user(using an Android App). Google fit History API is great but, if i'm correct, it only records physical activities such as foot/run/bike.

I've look for Google ActivityRecognitionClient API that gives me a way to know the transportation mode and confidence % for a certain time but still, i need to have the distance made with this transportation mode.

What i need is something like :

```
Date : 2019-04-24
Activity : 1
TransportationMode : Foot
distance : 10km

Date : 2019-04-24
Activity : 2
TransportationMode : car
distance : 100km
etc.
```

Any of you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about an API that you can use. However I found a research paper on ML model that predicts travel mode on the basis of GPS information. If you have sufficient time to develop your own AI model you may try this:
[AI model Predicting travel mode](http://file:///home/ist/Downloads/predicting-travel-mode-of-individuals-by-machine-learning.pdf)